# Shortcut for not having to type out `python3 program.py` when running python program

Tags: python, unix

Say I have the program `program.py` in a non-root directory. Thus, in order to run the program, I have to type `python3 program.py` every time. Is there a shortcut that I can enable in my unix environment where I type a specific command for a specific program to run. I.e. for the above, I want to just be able to type `program` and have the program run.

I am not greatly familiar with unix but I believe this has something to do with adding something to your path which I am unfamiliar with this method. Any references and/or support is greatly appreciated!!
Thanks!

Comment: If you need more info on `PATH`, try this question: [What is PATH on a Mac (UNIX) system?](/q/18409707/4518341)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the top of your file.

`#!/usr/bin/python3`, or wherever your install is.

Then `chmod +x your_file.py`.

Comment: I get: "zsh: command not found: run"

Comment: You would still need to run it.

That means `./name`

After you `chmod` it, you can remove .py from the extension so long as your python path is set in the first line comment.

Then you run it as I stated above.

Comment: Awesome it works. Thank you.

Comment: But can you also get rid of the `./` as well or no?

Comment: Yes, if you move it to /usr/bin or the user equivalent if you don't want it to be available system wide.